# View with a border

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-activity

How can I modify the small rectangles so that they are grey and have a red border around them just like in this image? Here is my code. I've tried to do so but my rectangles only appear as red. I need them to be equally spaced also. In addition is it possible to use weights to define width and height rather than pixels?

[image]

**Code**

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#808080" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@android:color/red" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@android:color/red"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@android:color/red" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@android:color/red" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@android:color/red" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@android:color/red" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a rough example on how to do that.
Here is a drawable you would use.
I named it emptyrect.  Save this in your drawables folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<solid android:color="#808080" /> 

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#FF0000" />

</shape>
```

Next is your layout.

It uses 100 gravity for the width.
Each emptyrect uses 20 of the 100 gravity.
There are 2 linear layouts.  1 is aligned top the other is aligned bottom.

gl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#808080" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizonal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:background="@drawable/emptyrect" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:background="@drawable/emptyrect" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="6" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:background="@drawable/emptyrect" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:background="@drawable/emptyrect" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:background="@drawable/emptyrect" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:background="@drawable/emptyrect" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="6" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:background="@drawable/emptyrect" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:background="@drawable/emptyrect" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You will want to create a shape drawable. Here is how I do it to have a black border with an orange bg so you will just want to modify the colors and sizes for whatever you need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
        android:shape="rectangle" >

    // solid fills in the shape with the color you want
    <solid android:color="@drawable/orange" />

    // stroke gives the outline with the specified width and color
    <stroke
        android:width="3px"
        android:color="@drawable/black" />

</shape>
```

You can use `<size>` to tell it how big you want them to be.

[Shape drawable docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape)

> In addition is it possible to use weights to define width and height rather than pixels?

You can do one or the other to have them equally sized and spaced but you will need to change it to a `LinearLayout`.

Without rewriting all of your code, you could have something like

```
<RelativeLayout
    // vertical orientation>
    <LinearLayout
        // horizontal orientation
        // width of 'match_parent'
        // height of wrap_content
        alignParentTop = true>
        <View
            //weight of maybe 1
            // width of '0'
            // height of wrap_content/>
        // maybe need an empty view in between each
        <View
            //weight of maybe .2
            // width of '0'
            // height of wrap_content/>
       // continue for all of your Views
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        // horizontal orientation
        // width of 'match_parent'
        // height of wrap_content
        alignParentBottom = true>
        <View
            //weight of maybe 1
            // width of '0'
            // height of wrap_content/>
        // maybe need an empty view in between each
        <View
            //weight of maybe .2
            // width of '0'
            // height of wrap_content/>
       // continue for all of your Views
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<View
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border" />
```

border.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="2dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="2dp"
    android:radius="2dp"
    android:topRightRadius="2dp" />

<gradient
    android:endColor="#707070"
    android:startColor="#707070" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#FF0000" />

<padding
    android:bottom="2dip"
    android:left="2dip"
    android:right="2dip"
    android:top="2dip" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

use the stroke attribute:

```
<stroke
        android:width="4dp"
        android:color="@color/red" />
```

stroke can only be used inside `<shape>HERE</shape>`

you can add a new mybackground.xml file and add it to your drawble folder
the xml file will contain the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="#77000000" />

    <corners android:radius="10dip" />

    <gradient
        android:angle="-90"
        android:endColor="#44FF0000"
        android:startColor="#CCFF0000" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="10dip"
        android:left="10dip"
        android:right="10dip"
        android:top="10dip" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dip"
        android:color="#000000" >
    </stroke>

</shape>
```

now instead of doing:
`android:background="@android:color/red"` you can do

```
android:background="@drawable/mybackground"
```

(btw the corner, gradient and padding attribute are just there so you would know what else is possible to do)

I hope this helps :)